# Updating record after change with jquery UI datepicker

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

I'm trying to update the db record once a data is selected with the datepicker. I have this, but it does not update the record.

```
var condate = $('input.datepicker').datepicker({
    dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy"
});

condate.change(function(){
    var getid = $(this).attr("id");
    var myid = getid.replace("condatum","");
    var mydate = $(this).val();
    var dataString = {id: myid, condatum: mydate};

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        cache: false,
        url:"inc/editfields.php",
        data: dataString,
        dataType:"html",
        success: function(response) { $('#condatum'+ myid).html(response); },
        error: function(xhr,err,e){ alert( "Error: " + err ); }
    });
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Seems to be working just fine, are you sure the URL is correct ?

Comment: Yes, the URL is correct. I double checked the PHP code but that is correct. Is the binding using the change function not ok?

Comment: Everything seems to be working just fine for me -> http://jsfiddle.net/Eaq2s/1/ (of course without testing the serverside)

Comment: The code works. It was the dateformat.